# Print list of pairs in Racket

Tags: lambda, foreach, racket

Programming in Racket/base,

I am trying to accomplish two things...

**First:**  I am trying to create a sorted list of pairs <String, Int>  from an already created hash-map.  I am fairly sure this part works but...

In order to check I want to print the list of pairs.

**Second:** I am having trouble with the correct way to reference each list entry, I have tried using lambda functions for iterating the list, but I don't know whether I need to use car and cdr for getting the pair arguments or if the way I have it coded with ~a for each entry will work.

'''

```
      (define sorted-keys (sort(hash->list countMap) #:key car string<?))
      
      (printf "The entries are: ")
        (for-each
         (lambda (entry) (entry (in-list sorted-keys))
           (printf "~a = ~a~n (car entry) (cdr entry)))
```

'''

I am brand new to Racket and I am struggling with the documentation regarding for/list and how to iterate over a list of pairs.  Should I be using "for-each" on a list of pairs while using lambdas?

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`For-each`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fmap..rkt%29._for-each%29%29) has these arguments: procedure and iterated collection. So, this will work:

```
(define my-hash (hash "Amy" 20 "John" 10 "Adam" 5 "Alice" 12))

(define sorted-list (sort (hash->list my-hash) string<? #:key car))

(printf "The entries are:~n")

(for-each (lambda (entry)
            (printf "~a = ~a~n" (car entry) (cdr entry)))
          sorted-list)
```

Note that `for-each` is used only for side-effects (for example, printing) and it doesn't return anything. You can use [`map`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fmap..rkt%29._map%29%29) for iterating which returns list:

```
(map (lambda (entry) (list (car entry) (+ 1 (cdr entry))))
     sorted-list)

=> (("Adam" 6) ("Alice" 13) ("Amy" 21) ("John" 11))
```

[`For/list`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/for.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._for%2Flist%29%29) has more options (see [Racket docs for `for`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/for.html)), but sometimes really doesn't matter which you use:

```
> (for/list ([entry sorted-list])
    (list (car entry) (+ 1 (cdr entry))))

(("Adam" 6) ("Alice" 13) ("Amy" 21) ("John" 11))
```

By the way, there's [`hash-for-each`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/hashtables.html#%28def._%28%28quote._%7E23%7E25kernel%29._hash-for-each%29%29), so you don't have to convert it:

```
(printf "~nThe entries are:~n")

(hash-for-each my-hash
               (lambda (key val)
                 (printf "~a = ~a~n" key val)))
```

And hashes have their own map version [`hash-map`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/hashtables.html#%28def._%28%28quote._%7E23%7E25kernel%29._hash-map%29%29) (which returns list):

```
> (hash-map my-hash
          (lambda (key val)
            (list (string-upcase key) val)))

(("ALICE" 12) ("JOHN" 10) ("AMY" 20) ("ADAM" 5))
```

See also [Racket docs](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/hashtables.html) for other functions useful for hash tables.

Comment: I cannot upvote as this is my first question posted to Stack Overflow, but I would like to thank you Martin for your concise and thourough response.  Your explanation really helped me get my code working and to further understand what I did wrong.

Comment: @MichaelEvenson See also [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) - even if you don't have privileges to vote, you can mark one answer as "accepted". This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: I did not know that was a thing, and now I have learned two things from you today.  Thank you again @Martin Puda